# How do I install TeamViewer Host?

Tags: 12.04, server, remote-access, teamviewer

How do I install TeamViewer 7 Host on Ubuntu Server 12.04?

Comment: If any queston was the solution, please mark that one. So everyone in the future and now knows what answer to use.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using the server edition, I will state all the necessary steps:

Download the deb

32 bit:

```
 wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
```

64 bit

```
wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

after that just install teamviewer:

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
```

or teamviewer_linuxx64.deb if you downloaded the 64 bits version.

It should work without wine, I just tested that.

But shouldn't you use another vnc client? Because teamviewer is nice and easy, but gives no particular use for a server.

Comment: Should add that SSH is so much better in terms of speed, followed by any VNC app.

Comment: Well, he asked for teamviewer, and as that is the question. I only suggested that he should use something else. But I think running teamviewer on a cli is impossible due to the fact it uses a gui, and I think that teamviewer accepts no arguments.

Comment: Yeah sure dont worry, just so the user knows some faster alternatives which can also be used as a remote connection.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site:

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx

and choose the `deb` download for your architecture (either x86 or 64)

Once you've downloaded it, opening it will take you to the software center where you can install it.

**Note that there is no host-only package for linux distros.**

Comment: as far as I know, you would still require Wine to run it.

Comment: From memory, yes, it lists wine as a dependency. OP didn't say that's a problem though

Comment: just checked it, it indeed launches with wine. But that can be resolved with a simple sudo apt-get install wine.

Comment: Does the deb not list wine as a dependency? I'm sure it did for me, although I may have had it installed already.

Comment: But he is not using a software center, he is using a server edition. Everything is cli.

Comment: Doesn't matter, software center is just a frontend to `apt`. `apt-get` will resolve dependencies

Comment: yeah I know, but since when did a server have a de? That's just not logical.